# Django exceptions gone after apache restart

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a apache + mod_wsgi production server, running on a debian. From time to time i got some django exception, but there is no misstake in my source code. After restarting apache the exceptions are gone.

Any idea?

Comment: What exceptions? What do they look like? Just stating you have exceptions won't help us help you figure out what the issue is.

Comment: They are allways different. But after restart all works fine. The excpetion is not the problem, the key is that there are no exception afte restart. Test with same environment and paramters. The exception are illogical. In my test environment all works perfect and unittests successfully passed. I tested my code again and again, that is not the problem, i think this is more an apache or wsgi problem.

Comment: you need to post the actual exception. We have no information to go on otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have some sort of import loop, order dependency or multi thread issue. When the problem occurs can be random and dependent on the order in which requests arrive or be dependent on concurrent requests occuring. In other words, doesn't show up immediately but some random time later. Restarting clears it but only in some mutch as you wait until it happens again.

Preloading your application code as described in:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html

has helped some people with this problem, but not everyone.

Tracking it done can be a PITA.